# Behaviour of Keras BinaryCrossentropy() loss function

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, keras

From the Keras source code, this is the definition of the BinaryCrossentropy() for the Numpy backend and the plot of the loss function for the values around logit 0 in both directions (appoaching to it from the sides):

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1. / (1. + np.exp(-x))

def binary_crossentropy(target, output, from_logits=False):
    if not from_logits:
        output = np.clip(output, 1e-7, 1 - 1e-7)
        output = np.log(output / (1 - output))

    return (target * -np.log(sigmoid(output)) +
            (1 - target) * -np.log(1 - sigmoid(output)))

loss = binary_crossentropy(np.array([-1,-.5,-.1,0,.1,.5,1]), np.array([1,.5,.1,0,-.1,-.5,-1]), from_logits=True)
plt.plot(loss)
```

[image]

Could anyone help with understanding why the minimum of the loss function is at point 4 `(0.1, -0.1)` instead of 3 `(0.0, 0.0)` when both prediction and target values are the same?

Comment: Your targets are not not valid.

Comment: It would be quite helpful if you could elaborate more your comment. You might be right but the way I understand this function is that both predictions and targets are logits, which have a (-inf, inf) domain.

Comment: This is a loss for classification, the targets are binary values {0, 1}, or probabilities in [0, 1].

Comment: Isn't the purpose of the logit conversion in the function to transform probabilities [0,1] into the (-inf,inf) logit range by doing log(p/(1-p))?

Comment: First of all, the transformation is applied only to outputs. Second, it is reversed using the sigmoid function when calculating the loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cross-entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) between two probability distributions $p$ and $q$ [is defined as](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074276/how-is-logistic-loss-and-cross-entropy-related)

$$
H(p, q) = E_p [-\log q] = -\sum_x p(x) \log q(x)
$$

In [machine learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990250/what-is-cross-entropy), $q$'s are the predicted probabilities, while $p$'s are the observed labels in $\{0, 1\}$, the "true probabilities". Both $p$ and $q$ need to be in $(0, 1)$, so your `targets` are wrong, leading to the results you have show.

For different reasons (usually computational ones), people sometimes prefer their models to return [log-odds (logits)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit), i.e. values in $(-\infty, \infty)$, rather then transforming them to probabilities. This is why functions as the one above accepts logits as inputs. However this only applies to the *predicted* values, not the target values. If your target values were unconstrained real numbers, then this would be a regression problem and you would be using the loss functions appropriate for regression (squared error, absolute error, Huber loss, etc.). Cross-entropy would not have any mathematical sense if the values of $p$ were unconstrained real numbers, while it has information-theoretic meaning if the values are probabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Tim, it's perfectly clear now